# Row renderer with height depending on row index

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have an `IDropInListItemRenderer` that is being used inside a `List`. The height of the row depends on both the data and it's position in the `List`'s view.

How do I remeasure as soon as the row index changes?

`updateDisplayList` doesn't get called every time, and also by that point it's too late because the `List` has already measured it.

**edit**

The effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to iOS where the header for a section sticks to the top
[image: iOS UITableView with sections]

Here is the basic renderer that doesn't measure correctly:

```
import mx.controls.Label;
import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
import mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer;
import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

public class MyRowRenderer extends UIComponent implements IListItemRenderer, IDropInListItemRenderer {
    private static const HEADER_HEIGHT:int = 20;
    private static const LABEL_HEIGHT:int = 20;

    private var _data:Object;
    private var _label:Label;
    private var _header:Label;
    private var _listData:BaseListData;

    public function MyRowRenderer() {
        super();
    }

    [Bindable("dataChange")]
    public function get data():Object {
        return _data;
    }

    public function set data(value:Object):void {
        this._data = value;
        invalidateProperties();
        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
    }

    [Bindable("dataChange")]
    public function get listData():BaseListData {
        return _listData;
    }

    public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void {
        _listData = value;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();

        _header = new Label();
        addChild(_header);

        _label = new Label();
        addChild(_label);
    }

    override protected function measure():void {
        super.measure();

        if (_label == null || _header == null) {
            return;
        }

        var h:Number = LABEL_HEIGHT;

        if (_listData.rowIndex == 0) {
            h += HEADER_HEIGHT;
        }

        explicitHeight = measuredHeight = height = h;
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void {
        super.commitProperties();

        _label.text = _data.label;
        _header.text = _data.header;
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        _header.visible = _header.includeInLayout = (_listData.rowIndex == 0);

        if (_header.visible) {
            _header.move(0, 0);
            _header.setActualSize(unscaledWidth, HEADER_HEIGHT);

            _label.move(0, HEADER_HEIGHT);
            _label.setActualSize(unscaledWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT);
        } else {
            _label.move(0, 0);
            _label.setActualSize(unscaledWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide working code? why don't try with inline itemRenderer any specific reason there?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a subclass of `List` and overriding the `shiftRow` function to dispatch a custom `RowIndexChangeEvent`. In the row renderer's `set listData` it adds an event listener to the owner for the `RowIndexChangeEvent` and invalidates it's properties, size and displaylist.